# Obtain the image´s path with Photo framework photo framework ios 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, path

Hi I save images in a specific album with photo framework, and This is my code:

```
[[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary] performChanges:^{
        PHAssetChangeRequest *assetChangeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest creationRequestForAssetFromImage:self.imagenSelecionada.image];

        if (self.assetCollection) {
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest *assetCollectionChangeRequest =   [PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest changeRequestForAssetCollection:self.assetCollection];
            [assetCollectionChangeRequest addAssets:@[[assetChangeRequest placeholderForCreatedAsset]]];
        }
    } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
        if (!success) {
            NSLog(@"Error creating asset: %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

I need to obtain the images´s path where the image was saved in order to save after in a data base SQLite.

Comment: where you able to find a solution here?